# Invoking SendGrid APIs from a Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, sendgrid

I am trying to send transactional emails from Salesforce by using the SendGrid API (via External Services) and Flow Builder.

Here is what I've done so far:

- Added the SendGrid auth credentials to Salesforce (Setup > Named Credentials)
- Imported the SendGrid v3 OpenAPI spec to Salesforce (Setup > External Services)

We now have over 300 SendGrid API operations we can conduct from within any Salesforce Flows.

We want to use the 'POST_Mail-Send' Flow Action to send an email, but I don't know how to setup the flow to accept the payload that SendGrid is looking for.

The only parameter I see in the Invokable Action is "Body" and I'm not sure how to pass values to it. The SendGrid API needs a 'from', 'to', 'dynamic_template_data', and 'template_id' according to their [docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-templates).

Here is a screenshot of where I'm stuck (also showing the 'Advanced' dropdown just in case, but I may not need it):

[image]

How do I construct a payload body to pass to the invokable action within my flow?

Comment: You're doing everything correctly. OpenAPI is a complex spec and External Services can't handle SendGrid API definition+schema. This is why you see `body` as an object rather than individual email attributes. Whether it's a bug or a known product limitation would be something you should inquire with Salesforce product support by opening a case. A _potential_ workaround is the HTTP Callout flow feature, it supports `POST` methods starting with [Summer '23 release](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_http_callout_post.htm&release=244&type=5)